# Failed unmounting /home during shutdown arch linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, shutdown, reboot

I've installed arch on my system multiple times and everything has worked fine, but since last installation I've been seeing messages : `Failed unmounting /home.` and `Failed unmounting /run/user/1000.` during shutdown or reboot procedure. I've searched arch forums for similar threads and found nothing to solve this problem despite multiple conversations on this topic.

Here is `journalctl -p 0..3 -xn` output:

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2015-08-02 15:24:27 IST, end at Tue 2015-08-04 21:29:57 IST. --
Aug 04 17:26:59 lenovo systemd-logind[315]: Failed to abandon session scope: Transport endpoint is not connected
Aug 04 17:26:59 lenovo systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /home.
-- Subject: Unit home.mount has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit home.mount has finished shutting down.
Aug 04 17:26:59 lenovo systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /run/user/1000.
-- Subject: Unit run-user-1000.mount has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit run-user-1000.mount has finished shutting down.
-- Reboot --
Aug 04 19:34:30 lenovo dhcpcd[320]: enp1s0: ipv6nd_sendrsprobe: sendmsg: Cannot assign requested address
Aug 04 19:34:40 lenovo dhcpcd[320]: enp1s0: DHCP lease expired
Aug 04 19:55:31 lenovo systemd-logind[339]: Failed to abandon session scope: Transport endpoint is not connected
Aug 04 19:55:31 lenovo systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /home.
-- Subject: Unit home.mount has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit home.mount has finished shutting down.
Aug 04 19:55:31 lenovo systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /run/user/1000.
-- Subject: Unit run-user-1000.mount has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit run-user-1000.mount has finished shutting down.
-- Reboot --
Aug 04 21:25:48 lenovo dhcpcd[309]: enp1s0: DHCP lease expired
Aug 04 21:26:46 lenovo dhcpcd[309]: enp1s0: DHCP lease expired
```

Here is `cat /etc/fstab` output:

```
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
# /dev/sda3
UUID=d98988d2-4106-4f72-bc14-492d1acbb4fb   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1

# /dev/sda1
UUID=166C-1970          /boot       vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro    0 2

# /dev/sda4
UUID=75c1fdba-3038-451e-ba11-adeb18ac99dc   /home       ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2

# /dev/sda2
UUID=89adf58d-e21e-4d12-8bd6-2d44314daa55   none        swap        defaults    0 0
```

and here is `lsblk` output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0    30G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0 430.8G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I've no idea what these messages mean or otherwise I would've definitely searched about it more. Thankyou.

Comment: Although this is not a solution for your problem, I wanted to inform you that there are several other people (including me) experiencing this or a similar issue. Here's a link to the [thread in the Archlinux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171087), and another [somewhat similar issue](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200469)

Comment: You can [add](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters#GRUB) [`debug`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Boot_debugging#Medium_Debug) kernel parameter to your kernel line and check if `journalctl` returns more specific log. Alternatively you can set temporary alias in [`~/.bash_aliases`](http://pkill-9.com/enabling-bash_aliases/): `alias umount='umount -v'`. If either of two ways produces more log messages, then post them.